# Construction of comoving tetrad frame

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have some system, for example the Earth orbiting the Sun.

In the Sun's rest frame we can define some basis $e_{\mu}$.

If the Earth has 4-velocity $u^{\nu}$, how would one transform to the Earth's rest frame (the comoving tetrad frame with the Earth.) $e_{\hat{\mu}}$, where $e_{\hat{\mu}}$ are orthogonal i.e. $e_{\hat{\mu}} \cdot e_{\hat{\nu}} = \eta_{\hat{\mu} \hat{\nu}}$ for Minkowski tensor $\eta$.

Thanks